# Null-Pointer Exception when starting Intent from MapView through MainActivity?

Tags: android, maps, nullpointerexception

I have a MapView in my app. On clicking an overlayItem, a bubble pops-up with information about the place.On clicking the icon, the user should go to another activity.

I first send the control from inside the

```
BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>.MapBalloonItemizedOverlay.onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item)
```

method to the MainActivity page using:

```
MainActivityObject.gotoMethod();
```

i.e

```
@Override
public boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item)
{
   MainActivityObject.gotoMethod();
    return true;
}
```

Then in that method I code:

```
try
    {
    Intent goIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(goIntent);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

***But I get the below null-pointer exception error:***

```
09-19 16:02:56.707: WARN/System.err(2454): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 16:02:56.717: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
09-19 16:02:56.717: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
09-19 16:02:56.717: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2678)
09-19 16:02:56.717: WARN/System.err(2454):     at towerCo.Android.Main.MapsActivity.showDetailpage(MapsActivity.java:897)
09-19 16:02:56.717: WARN/System.err(2454):     at towerCo.Android.MapOverLays.MapBalloonItemizedOverlay.onBalloonTap(MapBalloonItemizedOverlay.java:55)
09-19 16:02:56.717: WARN/System.err(2454):     at mapViewBalloon.BalloonItemizedOverlay$1.onTouch(BalloonItemizedOverlay.java:169)
09-19 16:02:56.717: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3762)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
09-19 16:02:56.727: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
09-19 16:02:56.738: WARN/System.err(2454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
09-19 16:02:56.738: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.738: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.738: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.738: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.738: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
09-19 16:02:56.738: WARN/System.err(2454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-19 16:02:56.747: WARN/System.err(2454):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It looks like it's the Intent constructor that's blowing up from a function called showDetailpage.  Can you post that code?  Is that where the gotoMethod is being called from?

Comment: Thank for the comment. I have updated the comment.I also read somewhere that I need to directly access the activity that contains my MapView and not create a new MainActivity Object.Please advise.

Comment: Does `MainActivityObject` extend `Activity`? How do you instantiate it?

Comment: I am not sure!I used MainActivity MainActivityObject =new MainActivityObject();

Comment: Check the class definition, ie.  `public class MainActivity extends Activity` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer in another post.I will repost it here for others:

[Mapview start new activity when a baloonOverlay is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071017/mapview-start-new-activity-when-a-baloonoverlay-is-clicked)

Replace this:

```
MainActivity MainActivityObject = new MainActivity (); 
sub.startCustomActivity();
```

with this:

```
Intent Details = new Intent(context, Tab.class); 
context.startActivity(Details);
```

So we basically have to use the context variable we got from the MapView passed in our overlay class to start our activity.

Thank You to all for helping me earlier. Appreciated!