# Starting Multiple map activities

Tags: android

Hi I am implementing two mapview in different activities they both works, the scenario is there is one large mapview which contains some projection points so when a point is clicked it should open up a new activity filled with some details. So my second activity is a scrollview layout that contains a small mapview at bottom which works fine

**ISSUE**: *but when i press back button and goes back to previous mapview i get some warnings and that mapview doesnt load anymore i get a half of the map screen with white background*

Main mapview: [mapView show overlay details when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923422/mapview-show-overlay-details-when-clicked)

so when i click on the balloon as shown in figure it opens up a new activity that also contains a mapview so when i press back button and gets back the main mapview(the one shown in figure above) cuts into half and i get these warnings:

```
02-22 14:39:39.806: WARN/System.err(7823): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down.
02-22 14:39:39.806: WARN/System.err(7823):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:284)
02-22 14:39:39.806: WARN/System.err(7823):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:238)
02-22 14:39:39.816: WARN/System.err(7823):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:175)
02-22 14:39:39.816: WARN/System.err(7823):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:325)
02-22 14:39:39.816: WARN/System.err(7823):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-22 14:39:39.826: WARN/System.err(7823):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-22 14:39:39.826: WARN/System.err(7823):     at com.google.common.io.android.AndroidHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
02-22 14:39:39.826: WARN/System.err(7823):     at com.google.common.io.android.GoogleHttpClient.executeWithoutRewriting(Unknown Source)
02-22 14:39:39.836: WARN/System.err(7823):     at com.google.common.io.android.GoogleHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
02-22 14:39:39.836: WARN/System.err(7823):     at com.google.common.io.android.GoogleHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
02-22 14:39:39.836: WARN/System.err(7823):     at com.google.common.io.android.AndroidHttpConnectionFactory$AndroidGoogleHttpConnection.getResponse(Unknown Source)
02-22 14:39:39.836: WARN/System.err(7823):     at com.google.common.io.android.AndroidHttpConnectionFactory$AndroidGoogleHttpConnection.openDataInputStream(Unknown Source)
02-22 14:39:39.846: WARN/System.err(7823):     at com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(Unknown Source)
02-22 14:39:39.846: WARN/System.err(7823):     at com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(Unknown Source)
02-22 14:39:39.846: WARN/System.err(7823):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

I found one post saying its not possible to implement two map view in an application, I found one solution here but didnt worked: 
[How to use multiple MapActivities/MapViews per Android application/process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379575/how-to-use-multiple-mapactivities-mapviews-per-android-application-process)

It says to start each mapview in different process as follows:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.directory.MapView1" android:process=":MapView1">
<activity android:name=".activity.directory.MapView2" android:process=":MapView2">
```

The above solution didnt worked for me, my code is as under:

**MainMapView Class**

```
public class CouponMapView extends MapActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.large_mapview);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
       // mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(false);
        mapView.setTraffic(false);
       // layout = findViewById(R.id.)

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mappointer);
        ItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView, getParent());
        OverlayItem overlayitem;
        GeoPoint point = null;
        double lat;
        double lng;

        try{
            tempData = dataArray.gettempData();         

            for (int i = 0; i < this.totalLimit; i++) {
                lat = Double.parseDouble(tempData.get(i).getLatitude());
                lng = Double.parseDouble(tempData.get(i).getLongitude());

                point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),(int) (lng * 1E6));

                overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, tempData.get(i).getId()+"", tempData.get(i).getInfo().getName());
                itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                itemizedoverlay.setBalloonBottomOffset(10);
                mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        try{
            final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
            mc.animateTo(point);
            mc.setZoom(16);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TfODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

**IM calling onTap method of this class to start a new activity**

```
public class ItemizedOverlay extends BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private int id;

    public ItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView, Activity activity) {
        super(boundCenter(defaultMarker), mapView);
        context = mapView.getContext();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        overlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return overlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return overlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index) {
        Intent Details = new Intent(context, Tab.class);
        Details.putExtra("Id", 1327);
        context.startActivity(Details);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The third class is the details class that contains another mapview implementation and is a simple linearlayout but includes a map. I dont think there is anything wrong with the above code but there must be something i am missing in the first class to refresh its view, though i have tried view.requestlayout/view.invalidate but they didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

> I am implementing two mapview in different activities they both works, the scenario is there is one large mapview which contains some projection points so when a point is clicked it should open up a new activity filled with some details.

I would not recommend this. Use one `MapActivity` with one `MapView` and change your zoom/center to be where the point is clicked. Override `onBackPressed()`, and if you are presently in "detail mode", change your zoom/center to be back where you were before. That way, you can do everything you want with only one `MapView`, and this problem goes away.

> So my second activity is a scrollview layout that contains a small mapview at bottom which works fine

Do not put a `MapView` in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: The problem was solved by starting a new intent and calling the mapActivity class again. That will create all the view again and you can override the backbutton to move through activities but each time it will be new activity.