# Got to location on map activity with click from another class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost, android-mapview, android-tabs

My app has three tabs, one of which is a Map. From the other two tabs I want the user to be able (after navigation through several screens) to go to the map tab and a certain location on the map with a button click from one of the screens which the user ends up on from the other two tabs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

referenced from method intentTest.xyz.com.intentTest$1.onClick

**1.intentTest.java:**

```
package intentTest.xyz.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class intentTest extends Activity {
  Button b;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);

    b.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(intentTest.this,second.class );
            startActivity(intent);                
        }
    });

   }
 }
```

**2.main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="First screen"
/>

<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="map"
android:id="@+id/b"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**3.second.java:**

```
package intentTest.xyz.com;

 import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
 import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class second extends MapActivity{
  MapView map;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
   map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
   }

 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return false;
  }
  }
```

**4.second.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0ujyc9Tw2cYvyPECIKTQIK0pwuL-UPa_sh4BpIw"
/>
```

**5.manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="intentTest.xyz.com"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".intentTest"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity android:name=".second"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
           <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
   </activity>

   </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  </manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, do you know of a way to move to a specific point in the map with the same button click, I thought it might be possible with bundling a string identifier with the intent and reading it on the map class but I'm really not sure. Also, Do you know how this would work with a tab set up? As I would surely have to set the current tab view to the map as well.

Comment: Refer this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923422/mapview-show-overlay-details-when-clicked